# Javascript focus() method not working with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script

I have tried using the focus() method by various ways in my Google Apps Script Project. I tried using both of these:

```
$("#elementID").focus();
```

and also

```
document.getElementById("elementID").focus();
```

But neither works. Am I missing something or is Caja sanitizing it? Also if the later is true are there any workarounds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387457/cannot-simply-force-focus-on-text-input-in-stand-alone-google-app-using-htmlserv

Comment: Ok that helped. But actually I am using **focus()** against the **onchange()** event of a **<select>** field. So, that can be said to be a user input event. So why isn't it working in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I build a page with HtmlService and it worked. 
Check this code:

Apps Script

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("pag").evaluate();
}
```

Html Template

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
<select id="selectCombo" onchange="setFocus(this)" >   
<option value="1" >A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>
<option value="3">C</option>
</select>     
<input type="text" class="focusField" id="myField" />
</form>   
<script>
function setFocus(obj) {   
  document.getElementById('myField').select();      
}
</script>

</html>
```

Apps Script URL [Here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxGvLxYQlww4JzjAuhYYPwLXJ0BVYygYcFHSbMJ9hca0qYCcDA/exec)

Comment: Your link for the app script does not work. Also triggering **focus()** with **onclick()** works fine for me. But I need to trigger it with **onchange()** event.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, to fix it I used this method:

JS:

```
function selectChange(elt)
{
  elt.changed = true;
  // ...
}
function selectClick(elt)
{
  if (elt.changed) {
    elt.changed = false;
    document.getElementById('myTarget').focus();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect" onChange="selectChange(this);" onClick="selectClick(this);"></select>
<input id="myTarget" />
```