# jQuery Accordion how to get enter to select button for active heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I am using an accordion in a dialog to go through different steps that the end user will need to do.  Each step has a button or text box with a button.     How can I get it so that when a user hits the enter key it activates the button associated with the active heading.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="accordion">

    <h3 id="Step1">Step 1:</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    To get started click "Setup" and it will configure this spreadsheet for use with the Connected Groups Add-on.
    </p>

    <p><button id="Step1B" class="action" onclick="step1()">Setup</button></p>
  </div>

  <h3 id="Step2">Step 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    To get started enter the name of your first contact group below then click "Create". 
    </p>
    <p><input type="text" id="gName">
    <button id="Step2B" class="action" onclick="step2()">Create</button></p>
  </div>
  <h3  id="Step3">Done</h3>
  <div>
    <p><center>
    Thank you for using Connected Groups.  More information or help can be found:
    </center>
    </p>
    <p><button id="thankYou" onclick="step3()">Close</button></p>
  </div>

</div>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
    });  
  }); // run on launch

  function step1(){
  alert("Step1");
  $('#Step2').click(); 
  };

    function step2(){
    var tb = $("#gName").val();
  alert("Step2: "+tb);
  $('#Step3').click(); 
  };

   function step3(){
  google.script.host.close();
  };

  </script>
```

Comment: This is actually part of a larger App script using htmlService.  I just trimmed it down to show only relevant code.   For the admin who took away the tag, I would like to keep it as HtmlService relies on Caja which is quite limiting and may effect the answer.

Comment: @Mogsdad Yes I know that part is from GAS, but I thought his problem is with javascript or jQuery, so there is no need for that tag as far as his server side GAS script is working fine. But anyways, that's what I thought. You can keep it. Cheers.

Comment: Are you just trying to open the next accordian on button click..? if so, there might be a better way of doing this.

Comment: @TJ I have the next solved (on-Click), I just don't know how to make it work on Enter.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get it so that when a user hits the enter key it activates the button associated with the active heading?

First, we can catch keypress events for input elements. If the keypress is an 'enter' key, then we will dispatch a `click()` to the 'active' button. We'll store that in a global variable, `window.actionButton`.

```
$(':input').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        window.actionButton.click();
    }
});
```

If we assume that each panel contains a single button with `class='action'`, then we can keep track of the 'active' button.

```
window.actionButton = ui.newPanel.find(".action");
```

The [activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event fires whenever a header (+ panel) gets selected. During the page load, we will bind a function to that action, and have it update `window.actionButton`.

```
activate: function (event, ui) {
    window.actionButton = ui.newPanel.find(".action");
},
```

The workflow improves if we move the focus to highlight the intended action. Ideally, focus should go to the next input, whatever that is, but in this simple accordion it's sufficient to move to the appropriate button:

```
window.actionButton.focus();
```

Unfortunately, when running in Google Apps Script HtmlService, we can target a programmatic button click but cannot control focus: [Cannot simply force focus on text input in stand-alone Google App using HtmlService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387457/cannot-simply-force-focus-on-text-input-in-stand-alone-google-app-using-htmlserv/15388157#15388157) You'll find that the jsFiddle operates differently than when in HtmlService because of this.

#### Script

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL1qt3e0/2/).

```
<div id="accordion">
     <h3 id="Step1">Step 1:</h3>

    <div>
        <p>To get started click "Setup" and it will configure this spreadsheet for use with the Connected Groups Add-on.</p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="Step1B" class="action" value="Setup" />
        </p>
    </div>
     <h3 id="Step2">Step 2</h3>

    <div>
        <p>To get started enter the name of your first contact group below then click "Create".</p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="gName" />
            <button id="Step2B" class="action">Create</button>
        </p>
    </div>
     <h3 id="Step3">Done</h3>

    <div>
        <p>
            <center>Thank you for using Connected Groups. More information or help can be found:</center>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="thankYou" class="action">Close</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * On document load, set up accordion & event handlers
   */
  $(function() {
     $("#accordion").accordion({
         heightStyle: "content",
         // Handle activate event by setting a new "actionButton", 
         // and putting it into focus.
         activate: function (event, ui) {
             //alert(ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
             window.actionButton = ui.newPanel.find(".action");
             window.actionButton.focus();
         },
         // Likewise for create event
         // This doesn't set focus - why not?
         create: function  (event, ui) {
             //alert(ui.panel.attr('id'));
             window.actionButton = ui.panel.find(".action");
             window.actionButton.focus();
         }
     });

     // Click handlers, assigned upon load
     $('#Step1B').click(function () {
         alert("Step1");
     });

     $('#Step2B').click(function () {
         var tb = $("#gName").val();
         alert("Step2: " + tb);
     });

     $('#Step3').click(function () {
         google.script.host.close();
     });

     // Setup keypress event handler for all inputs 
     // If 'enter' is pressed, click the current actionButton.
     $(':input').keyup(function (event) {
         if (event.keyCode == 13) {
             window.actionButton.click();
         }
     });
  });

</script>
```