# jquery focus method not working with google spreadsheet when trying to focus on input in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am developing an app for googlesheet. focus() doesn't work for me.
    i have tried using autofocus property also. that also doesn't work because of caja security.
        Here is my code:

```
> code.gs code
> =============
function onOpen() {
    ui.createMenu('MyApp').addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showSidebar').addToUi();
}


function showSidebar() {
      ui.showSidebar(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myapp.html').evaluate());
}


>myapp.html code
>=============
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#mypwd").focus();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="mypwd" type="password" value=""/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I've had the same problem.  I wanted to set the focus when an HTML page opened for the first time, and couldn't get it to work.  If it's a bug, or a suggestion for an improvement, you can report it here:  [Google Documentation - Bugs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue a couple of weeks ago. Like you mentioned, unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on how you look at it) this is a result of Caja sanitizing your code. Take a look at Corey G's  comments here:

[Cannot simply force focus on text input in stand-alone Google App using HtmlService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387457/cannot-simply-force-focus-on-text-input-in-stand-alone-google-app-using-htmlserv)

There isn't really a workaround, other than to tie .focus() to a user click event.